# Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute in my React App. Passing data from api

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need help understanding and fixing this bug:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `country-info-list`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: country-info-list="true" or country-info-list={value.toString()}.
    in ul (at CountryInfo.js:38)
    in div (at CountryInfo.js:13)
    in ul (at CountryInfo.js:11)
    in div (at CountryInfo.js:9)
    in CountryInfo (at Infopage.js:42)
    in div (at Infopage.js:35)
    in Infopage (at App.js:24)
    in Route (at App.js:23)
    in Switch (at App.js:19)
    in main (at App.js:18)
    in div (at App.js:16)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:15)
    in LoadingContextProvider (at App.js:14)
    in App (at src/index.js:10)
    in ThemeContextProvider (at src/index.js:9)
```

Here is the code I believe is causing the problem because when I comment out the code the error disappears:

```
  <ul country-info-list>
            <li className='info-list-item'>
              <span className='sub-title'>Currencies: </span>
              {currencies.map((currency) => {
                return <span key={uuid()}>{currency.name}</span>;
              })}
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message mentions, "If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: country-info-list="true""

That attribute is not standard in html/jsx and therefore React does not know what to do with it and gives you a warning. Try this:

```
<ul country-info-list="true">
        <li className='info-list-item'>
          <span className='sub-title'>Currencies: </span>
          {currencies.map((currency) => {
            return <span key={uuid()}>{currency.name}</span>;
          })}
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That worked. However I was silly and completely missed the fact I hadn't added className='country-list-info'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly pass the boolean as string to the component.

```js
<ul country-info-list='true'>
  <li className='info-list-item'>
    <span className='sub-title'>Currencies: </span>
       {currencies.map((currency) => {
          return <span key={uuid()}>{currency.name}</span>;
        })}
   </li>
</ul>
```